# Resolving "Cannot load file or Assembly" runtime exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, reference, .net-assembly

For years, this kind of error is giving me LOTS of headaches trying to figure out why an application that compiles perfectly fails at startup.

I mostly get this with 3rd party assemblies, and specially in applications that run over the full .NET Framework.

My question is: how do we fix them?

- Is there an automated way to fix them?
- Is there a tool to find the transitive references and their versions?
  * Is Assembly Binding in app.config the only way to resolve the conflicts when the assemblies are from 3rd parties?

Comment: I've always used fuslogvw.exe to find these. You can find details here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty broad question, but here are some tips:

1. Read [this article on how runtime binding works](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.110).aspx).
2. Deploy DLLs in the same folder as the executable, or in the [GAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache), or, if you absolutely  must, use a [probing path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).
3. Compile with the same version you intend to deploy.  If you have an updated DLL and don't want to recompile, you can try a [binding redirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx).
4. If you run into problems, use the [Fusion logs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx) to troubleshoot.